# how to remove square brackets in my print statement

Tags: python, sorting

Sort the k arrays individually and concatenate them.
Input Description:
First line contains the number of arrays. Subsequent lines contain the size of the array followed by the elements of the array.

Output Description:
An array containing the sorted elements of k sorted arrays

Sample Input :
3
2
98 12
6
1 2 3 8 5 9
1
11
Sample Output :
12 98 1 2 3 5 8 9 11

`````
a=input()
b=input()
c= input().split()
C=str(sorted(c))
d=input()
e=input().split()
E=str(sorted(e))
f=input()
g=input().split()
G=str(sorted(g))
x=C+E+G
print(*x)````

#output
[ ' 1 2 ' ,   ' 9 8 ' ] [ ' 1 ' ,   ' 2 ' ,   ' 3 ' ,   ' 5 ' ,   ' 8 ' ,   ' 9 ' ] [ ' 1 1 ' ]````
`desired output`
#i want my output as
Sample Output :
12 98 1 2 3 5 8 9 11
`````

Comment: `C = ", ".join(c)` do the same for the others

Comment: thanks for the comment but unfortunately its not giving crt answer

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
val = "[ ' 1 2 ' ,   ' 9 8 ' ] [ ' 1 ' ,   ' 2 ' ,   ' 3 ' ,   ' 5 ' ,   ' 8 ' ,   ' 9 ' ] [ ' 1 1 ' ]"
print(re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', val))
```

I am sure it work's for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = C + E + G
x = x.replace('[', '').replace(']', ' ').replace("'", '').replace(',', '')
print(x)
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, then You don't need to convert your list to string.

```
a=input()  # Number of arrays (let's say 3)

b=input()  # Length of first array (let's say 3)

c= list(map(int, input().split()))  # read a list of integer from user

# C=str(sorted(c)) this line is a bug. sorting on strings (i.e. 100 is bigger than 2)

c.sort()  # here we sorted a list of integers which is correct

d=input()  # length of second array (let's say 6)

e= list(map(int, input().split())) # again reading list of integers

# E=str(sorted(e)) # again a bug. Sorting the strings

e.sort()  # sorting list of INT

f=input()  # length of 3rd array (let's say 1)

g= list(map(int, input().split()))  # reading list of INT

# G=str(sorted(g)) # again a bug : )
g.sort()

x = c + e + g  # '+' operator on a list concatenates them

print(*x)
```

Sample Input:

```
3
3
3 2 1
6
6 5 4 3 2 1
1
1
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 1
```

This should work fine.
Cheers.!